# How can I Connect my domain name to my Azure Virtual Machine IP?

Tags: azure, dns

I am having a virtual machine on Azure running a website with IP Address http://13.67.182.83/

I am having also a domain name called nit-eg.com that I need it to point to the IP address

I changed the A records and CName to point to the IP but this made the domain name to be down and gave me the following error
This site can’t be reached

www.nit-eg.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
Search Google for nit
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

So that I changed the CName to point to the old site again and left the A records points to the new site

Now the old site is the one that is working but I need to make the new one working so that I expect that there is something to be done in the virtual machine itself to make the site running

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution after googling for some time
I created a Fully Qualified Domain Name then I pointed my CName alias to the site URL

This link will be helpful
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-portal-create-fqdn/

Comment: The above link is 404'ed at the moment:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/create-fqdn